# event.latLng and .getPath() return the coordinates of the map center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing a project using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 and I'm seeing some very puzzling output to the console.

I initialize the map like so:

```
function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.790113, -87.600732),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Then, later (but still within `initialize`), I have:

```
function addTimestampToLatLng(event) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, userPolyline, 0.000001)) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            title: '#' + userPolyline.getPath().getLength(),
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
        console.log(event.latLng);
        console.log(userPolyline.getPath());
        console.log(twoClosestPointsOnPolyline(event.latLng, userPolyline));
    }
}
```

which is called by an event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addTimestampToLatLng);
```

The strange thing is that every single coordinate printed to the console is the same coordinate - lb: 41.79021883761604, mb: -87.60098531842232 - the center of the map.  The strange part is that the code works perfectly in every way except when I try to print to the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling the function?  What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: I edited the question to show how the function is called - it's called via an event listener.

Comment: The reported behavior still doesn't make sense with the provided code. How about a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?